# Suggest REST/Service design for collection in 'DTO' response/request

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

Just learning REST and ServiceStack and asking for suggestion how to build this example schema:

I have a `User` object with those fields:

```
public class User
{
   public string ID {get;set;
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public List<int> OrderID {get;set;}     // inner collection
   //  all other fields
 }
```

I have a `Service` class:

```
public class UserService : Service
{
   public List<User> Get(User UserRequest)
   {
      List<User> lstUsers = // Somehow polulate a collection of Users
      return  lstUsers;
   }

   // Other functions
 }
```

and a AppHost file (self hosted for now)

```
 public UserHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
 {
     public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
     {
            Routes
               .Add<User>("/UserInfo")
               .Add<User>("/User/{ID}");
      }
  }
```

Everything working fine: the client (browser) send an empty 'User' request and receive collection of `User` objects,  but what I need to add is to get specific `User` request. For example I want to receive (and change) all Orders with specific `User` ID.

For example `User` with ID = 2 has a collection of 10 `OrderID`. So I though I can build an URI like this: /MyHost/2/Orders   and it will return collection of `Order` objects.

I already tried to add another DTO object `Order` and bind it to routes like this:

```
  Route.Add<Order>("/User/{ID}/Oders")
```

but it does not work. The screen (at least in browser) always stay blank and it seems no response is coming from SS.

Is it a RESFull way of doing things ? How It could be implemented in ServiceStack ?  and could you provide a little code example (even schematic) how to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return a list of orders for a given user, then binding to the URL `"/User/{ID}/Orders"` is the RESTful way, yes.

With ServiceStack I normally prefer to define request and response classes, where request class will have all the possible input parameters and response defines the resulting object. Though often these to can be combined like `User` in the example.

As `{ID}` in the URL refers to the user ID, it's better to name it `{UserID}` and also have this property on your request class.

Probably you can just have UserID on the `Order` class:

```
public class Order
{
    public string ID { get; set; } // order ID
    public string UserID { get; set; } // user ID - also request param
    // ...
}

Routes.Add<Order>("/User/{UserID}/Oders");
```

Now, UserID from the URL is mapped to your UserID property and you can use it to query the db, etc.

Each request class normally corresponds to another service class with your app logic. Thus,

- for `User` you have `UserService : RestServiceBase<User>`,
- for `Order` there is `OrderService : RestServiceBase<Order>`.

When ServiceStack sees this URL mapping `Routes.Add<Order>("/User/{UserID}/Oders")` it knows to invoke `OrderService` for a given URL.

```
public class OrderService : RestServiceBase<Order>
{
    public override object OnGet(Order request)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: But how I could detect (in function `Get(User UserRequest)`) if the URL was /User/123   or /User/123/Orders ???

Comment: Edited answer to add more info. Basically /User/123 and /User/123/Orders should be processed by two diff. services. One returns users, another returns orders. They just happen to share part of the url path. For orders there will be another method (in another class) `Get(Order orderRequest)`.